# Substitution instance for propositional logic in natural language

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Referring to **Understanding Arguments 9th edition**, there is some exercise about the propositional logic as follows:

Which of the following propositions is a substitution instance of “p ^ q ^ q”?

1. The night is young, and you’re so beautiful, and my flight leaves in thirty
   minutes.
2. The night is young, and you’re so beautiful, and my flight leaves in thirty
   minutes, and my flight leaves in thirty minutes.
3. You’re so beautiful, and you’re so beautiful, and you’re so beautiful.

Most of the answers I found said that 2 and 3 are substitution instance for p ^ q ^ q but I do not understand why 3 is a substitution instance. Can anyone elaborate on the reason behind this?

Much appreciated

Comment: For 3, take $p = q = $ “you’re so beautiful”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic rule for substituting sentences for propositional letters is: same letter, same substitution.

It is *not* required that different letters get different substitutions.

Ok, that's the standard convention. Why?

We could have adopted a different convention, but it would take make for annoying complications. Take the inference

(*) You're so beautiful and you're so beautiful, hence you're so beautiful.

Valid, and on the standard understanding, it can be treated as application of either one of the usual $\land$ elimination rules, i.e. the rules "from $p \land q$ you can infer $p$" and "from $p \land q$ you can infer $q$". But not so, if we insist on different propositional letters getting different substitutions: we'd then have to recognise a third $\land$ elimination rule, "from $p \land p$ you can infer $p$". Which would add a complication to our deduction system for no evident gain. And the complications ramify ...